# Data extract from table's using date condition

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

Table 1:

```
PHONE_NUMBER | DATE
--------------------------    
   10005     | 5/10/2013
   15555     | 7/17/2013
   58746     | 9/20/2013
```

Table 2:

```
PHONE_NUMBER | DATE
--------------------------    
   10005    | 5/12/2013
   10005    | 5/16/2013
   15555    | 6/17/2013
   15555    | 7/19/2013
   58746    | 8/22/2013
   58746    | 12/26/2013
   58746    | 9/20/2013
```

From the above two tables, I want to extract data from Table 2 by mapping Table 1 phonenumber against table 2 phonenumber and  the date in the Table 2 can exactly the same date or +/-5 days of the respective phonenumber's date of the table 1's.

Table 2 will have duplicated phonenumbers and all the duplicates matching the above condition should extract.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question this should meet the requirement:

```
SELECT
        t2.phone_number
      , convert(varchar(10),t2.[date],121) as t2_date
      , convert(varchar(10),t1.[date],121) as t1_date
      , datediff(DAY,t1.[date], t2.[date]) as diff_dates
FROM table2 AS t2
INNER JOIN table1 AS t1 ON t2.phone_number = t1.phone_number
                       AND t2.[date] between dateadd(day,-5,t1.[date]) and dateadd(day,5,t1.[date])
```

see: [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a76ae/7)

results from the sample data:

```
| PHONE_NUMBER |    T2_DATE |    T1_DATE | DIFF_DATES |
|--------------|------------|------------|------------|
|        10005 | 2013-05-12 | 2013-05-10 |          2 |
|        15555 | 2013-07-19 | 2013-07-17 |          2 |
|        58746 | 2013-09-20 | 2013-09-20 |          0 |
```

Answer (score 2):

/*Assuming your date fileds are of valid date data type */

```
SELECT a.* FROM TABLE1 a INNER JOIN TABLE2 b 
ON a.phone=b.phone AND (a.[date]=b.[date] OR b.[date] BETWEEN DATEADD(day,-5,b.[date]) AND DATEADD(day,5,b.[date]))
```